# How would you combine an array of lines into another array where lines that are not labeled are combined with the previous line?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a multi-line comment where certain lines have labels.

For example:

```
[
'Label1: this is the first line', 
'Label2: this is the second line', 
'this is the third line', 
'this is the fourth line', 
'Label3: this is the fifth line' ]
```

I'd like to compress this array so that recognizes when a line does not have a label, it is attached the last line that has a label.

Desired result:

```
[ 
'Label1: this is the first line', 
'Label2: this is the second line \n this is the third line \n this is the fourth line', 
'Label3: this is the fifth line' ]
```

I'm trying a double loop, but it's identifying lines that are just not labeled with that current index.

```
else if (!isLineLabeled(lines[j+1], labels[i])){
}
```

```
function isLineLabeled(line, label) {
    return line.trim().toLowerCase().startsWith(label.toLowerCase());
}

function combineLines(lines) {
    let arr = [];
    const labels = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3'];
    for (let i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < lines.length; j++) {
            if (isLineLabeled(lines[j], labels[i])) {
                linesObj.push(lines[j]);
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce into an array, whose keys are labels and whose values are that label's associated string. If a label isn't found in one of the original strings, add it to the array at the previous label found:

```js
const input = [
  'Label1: this is the first line',
  'Label2: this is the second line',
  'this is the third line',
  'this is the fourth line',
  'Label3: this is the fifth line'
];

let lastLabel;
const output = input.reduce((a, line) => {
  const labelMatch = line.match(/^([^:]+): ?(.*)/);
  if (!labelMatch) {
    a[a.length - 1] += `\n${line}`;
  } else {
    a.push(line);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Example snippet for lines with labels only:

```js
const input = ['Steps:', '1. one', '2. two', '3. three']

let lastLabel;
const output = input.reduce((a, line) => {
  const labelMatch = line.match(/^([^:]+): ?(.*)/);
  if (!labelMatch) {
    a[a.length - 1] += `\n${line}`;
  } else {
    a.push(line);
  }
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is awesome, but I did encounter an issue on lines where they are only labels. For example:

```
[ 'Steps:', '1. one', '2. two', '3. three']
```

Comment: Simple enough, just change the `+` to a `*` to match zero or more characters rather than one or more characters

Comment: You're a wizard! Thanks! This is the perfect solution.

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted to indicate that the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not comfortable with regex, here's a function without it (I've used Lists instead of Arrays but you catch the drift)...

```
    public static List<string> GetLabelledList(List<string> list){
        var returnList = new List<string>();
        var currentString = string.Empty;
        foreach(var s in list){
            if(!s.StartsWith("Label")) {
                if(currentString != string.Empty){
                    currentString += " \n ";
                }
                currentString += s;
            }else{
                if(currentString != string.Empty){
                    returnList.Add(currentString);
                }
                currentString = s;
            }
        }
        if(currentString != string.Empty){
            returnList.Add(currentString);
        }
        return returnList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce` to generate a new array with your condition.

```js
const arr = [
  'Label1: this is the first line',
  'Label2: this is the second line',
  'this is the third line',
  'this is the fourth line',
  'Label3: this is the fifth line'
];

const result = arr.reduce((result, currentItem) => {
  if (currentItem.startsWith('Label')) {
    result.push(currentItem);
  } else {
    result[result.length - 1] += ` ${currentItem}`;
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```